# Anyone who updated to SDK 5.0 having issues with splitActionBarWhenNarrow?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-5.0-lollipop

I just updated my SDK and started my app back up (it was running fine right before the update) and now my split action bar is not splitting. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, here is my setup:

```
 <activity android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" ....>
 <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
                       android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
 </activity>
```

I've tested this on a GS3 4.4 and on a Nexus 4 which also has 4.4. I'll test other devices in a bit.

Thanks.

EDIT: looks like the split actionbar is gone so I'll have to figure something else out.

Comment: "looks like the split actionbar is gone so I'll have to figure something else out" - do you have a reference to support that? Make it an answer, I'd be glad to upvote

Comment: Actually I do, I'll make it an answer https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77632

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the split actionbar is no longer supported under L and it is recommended that you use the new [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html)

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77632

Comment: It is also in the suppport library v7